# Не отправляются данные формы в телеграм

Tags: php, curl

есть форма на сайте, стоит задача отправлять данные в телеграм канал. Т.к. ркн заблокировал делаю через curl

```
<?php

// сюда нужно вписать токен вашего бота
define('TELEGRAM_TOKEN', 'XXXXXXX');

// сюда нужно вписать ваш внутренний айдишник
define('TELEGRAM_CHATID', '-XXXXXX');


$success = 'Сообщение отправлено';
$text_error = 'Форма не заполнена';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

//данные из форм
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']);

// сообщение
$tmtext = array(
"Имя" => $name,
"Телефон" => $phone,
);
//собираем все в кучу
$txt='';
foreach($tmtext as $key => $value) { 
     $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b>: ".$value."%0A"; 
  }


message_to_telegram($name);
function message_to_telegram($text)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
        $ch,
        array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TELEGRAM_TOKEN . '/sendMessage',
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                'chat_id' => TELEGRAM_CHATID,
                'text' => $text,
            ),
            CURLOPT_PROXY => 'IP',
            CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => 'admin:login',
            CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => CURLPROXY_HTTP,
            CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
        )
    );
    curl_exec($ch);
} 



?>
```

Если просто сообщение отправлять то оно доходит, но не могу выхватить с формы, помогите пожалуйста решить задачу

Answer (score 0):

Используйте SDK вместо кастомного кода. Стабильный репозиторий - https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Comment: такое решение мне не подходит, там вроде как обязательно надо ставить на laravel